# Show Build date and time in Marlin 2.0

Tags: marlin

Is there a command to show the compile date and time of the Marlin 2.0 firmware? Also, is there a way to show this info at boot up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show the compile date and time during bootup by changing the constant STRING_SPLASH_LINE2 in Configuration.h:

```
#define STRING_SPLASH_LINE2 __DATE__ " " __TIME__
```

Comment: From Sanity Check: STRING_SPLASH_LINE[12] are now obsolete. Please remove them from Configuration.h.

Comment: Apparantly, the possibility to change the text was removed ([Invariant Marlin bootscreen, #15057](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/pull/15057)), so this only works for versions prior to August 28.

Comment: So I guess I'll have to write the functionality myself and hope that Marlin adopts it.

Comment: Seeing as they deliberately removed this functionality, I don't thinks that's going to happen.
If I'm reading the [source code](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/3ac76f048973e1ecb5ea6f2c50eb5990bbd6a5b9/Marlin/src/lcd/HD44780/ultralcd_HD44780.cpp#L470) correctly, there should be a `STRING_SPLASH_LINE3` that is printed at boot time. Haven't tried it though.

Comment: Yes, I saw something like that to. But I also saw the comment about it being deprecated. Ah well, at least its the "correct" answer.

Comment: apparently the data and build are printed durning the board startup sequence.  that said, i added the below line to my **Configuration.h** `#define CUSTOM_MACHINE_NAME "ipatchs cr10s pro, marlin build "  __DATE__ " " __TIME__`