# Show build date and time in Marlin 2.1 firmware?

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, firmware

I'm trying to find out how to format the `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` options in Marlin.

This is NOT a duplicate of ([Show Build date and time in Marlin 2.0](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10844/show-build-date-and-time-in-marlin-2-0?newreg=652849c3d77f4bcfa4c009df0d2a9ba1)).

When compiling my firmware I have a line in my configuration.h

`#define CUSTOM_MACHINE_NAME __DATE__ " " __TIME__ " Ender-3"`

But on the printer it is showing

> Dec  5 2022 18:25:13 Ender-3

I want the format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm. Example "12/05/2022 18:25 Ender-3"

Answer (score 1):

`__DATE__` and `__TIME__` are C++ pre-processor macros with a predefined format. I don't think that there's any way to change them at compile time.

Comment: Spot on! There is a way (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697820/)), but that requires you to interpret the string and create your own format based on the default string.